# django CreateView with SuccessMessageMixin error: no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I tried to use SuccessMessageMixin with CreateView but got an error.

I used it with UpdateView and it worked.

It'd be nice to get a hint about what to do next. Thanks.

Repo: https://github.com/jeremy886/DjangoBasics/blob/DjangoForms/courses/views.py

Error:

```
AttributeError at /courses/2/create_quiz/

'Quiz' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/courses/2/create_quiz/
Django Version:     2.0.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'Quiz' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\jeremy\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\messages\views.py in form_valid, line 12
```

Code:

```
class QuizCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = "course"
    pk_url_kwarg = "course_pk"
    context_object_name = 'course'
    form_class = forms.QuizForm
    template_name = "courses/quiz_create.html"
    success_message = "%(title)s was created successfully"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        course_pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        course = get_object_or_404(models.Course, pk=course_pk)
        context["course"] = course
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        course_pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        quiz_form = form.save(commit=False)
        quiz_form.course = get_object_or_404(models.Course, pk=course_pk)
        # find a way to add "Successfully added!" message
        return super().form_valid(quiz_form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        course_pk = self.kwargs["course_pk"]
        return reverse_lazy('courses:detail', kwargs={'pk': course_pk})
        # More: how to get the quiz id from the above quiz form
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `form_valid` function: `return super().form_valid(quiz_form)`. It should be `return super().form_valid(form)` instead.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    course_pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    form.instance.course = get_object_or_404(models.Course, pk=course_pk)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: It works now. I don't think I can figure this out by reading docs. Much appreciated!

Comment: @JeremyChen `form.save(commit=False)` return model instance, and that's was the reason of error. Example of using `form.instance` syntax you may find here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user